# How to activate whitespace-mode for a cc-mode buffer from .dir-locals.el?

Tags: whitespace, local-variables

I'd like to enable `whitespace-mode` from a .`dir-locals.el` file such that when I open a file managed by `cc-mode`, I will see trailing spaces highlighted with the whitespace face.

I think I'm close. This is what I have in my `.dir-locals.el`, but its not quite enough.

```
((cc-mode . ((whitespace-style . (face trailing))            
             (whitespace-active-style . (face trailing))))
```

But if I <kbd>M-x</kbd>`whitespace-toggle-options` and choose <kbd>f</kbd>, then the trailing whitespace is highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the special "variable" `eval` as described in [Specifying File Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).

This `.dir-locals.el` code enables `whitespace-mode` for me:

```
((c++-mode
  (eval . (whitespace-mode))))
```

(I use Emacs 24.4.1.)

Comment: Except I would *strongly* recommend using the more readable (albeit entirely equivalent) dotted pair syntax: `(eval . (whitespace-mode))`

Comment: @phils: Sounds good; I'll update the answer. (Apparently `add-dir-local-variable` does not care about formatting.)